Esiste il femminile plurale di "anacoreta"? È "anacorete"?
Per inciso, non mi ero mai concentrato prima sulla mancanza del femminile nelle voci del vocabolario. Cioè, dovunque cerco "leone", è sempre riportato anche il femminile "leonessa" (qui la pagina del GDLI), ma per "bello" (qui e qui) non è mostrato esplicitamente assieme alla variazione di numero.
E mi pare pure di capire che sia un fatto risaputo.
Al di là di ciò, esiste il plurale femminile di anacoreta?
Wikitionary dice di sì. E Olivetti pure. È anacorete?

Wiktionary ha i pregi e difetti di tutti i wiki, ma comunque va preso cum grano salis. E il dizionario Olivetti per me è stato sempre misterioso: più si cercano informazioni e meno se ne trovano: chi l'ha compilato? con quali criteri? con quali fonti? Non c'entra ovviamente niente con la Olivetti di Adriano Olivetti. Il responsabile è un certo Enrico Olivetti, a sua volta misterioso, e il vocabolario stesso lascia spesso a desiderare.
I vocabolari di cui personalmente mi fido (il Grande dizionario della lingua italiana, Treccani, Zingarelli, Devoto-Oli, De Mauro) sono concordi nel registrare “anacoreta” soltanto come nome maschile (e col plurale in “-i”). (E, come controprova, per parole in qualche modo analoghe che sono state usate anche al femminile, la cosa è registrata, come per esempio nel caso di “esteta” o “asceta”, anche se effettivamente spesso non viene dato esplicitamente il plurale femminile.)
Poi, l'italiano è una lingua robusta: nulla ci vieta di usarla al femminile e coniarne un plurale.

Di questi Enrico non ci si può fidare :P
